# Format string to formatted date time in a C# model property

Tags: c#, datetime, attributes

Suppose a class like the following in C#:

```
    [Serializable]
    [JsonObject]
    public class HistoricalValue
    {
        [JsonProperty("record_date")]
        public string RecordDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("pay_date")]
        public string PayDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ex_div_date")]
        public string ExDivDate { get; set; }
    }
```

It would be extremely beneficial for me to be able to format DateTime data that are of type string in the properties to a specific date time string format let's say "dd-MMM-yyyy". Is it possible to achieve this through attributes?
I have tried the following code without success:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}")]
    public string PayDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a few rules handling DateTimes. In no particular order:

- Always store and retrieve the UTC DateTime. Let the ToString function at the enduser decide wich local Timezone and Format to dispaly it as. You really do not want to [deal with Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) if you can avoid it/leave it to someone else. Obvious exceptions are Webservers.
- For that reason, also always use DateTime - Date alone is not enough. If you tell me it is "27th December" I can show you up to 23/24th of the world that disagree. In some cases by several days (timezones can be really wierd)
- Never Store, Read or Transmit a DateTime as String if you can avoid it. If there is a internal Format, always use it instead.
- If for some reason you have to transmit it as string (XML, Serialsiation), always pick a fixed String Encoding and Format to be used at all Ends. XML will usually deal with Encoding (it carries the encoding used). I am not sure about other serialsiation techniques.

For your specific case:
I would not expose the DateTime as string to begin with. I would expose it as DateTime instance. Transalting it into strings should be left to the GUI and the Serialize/Deseriablize Function.

I might even consider transmtiting the DateTime as a Tick count (effectivel a big Integer) if I asume it will always be another .NET Application on the other end. Naturally with JSON you propably want something like strings instead.

Comment: Thank you for your points. I agree with all of them, but the issue here is that I am not the author of the code and nor the designer of the data. This is handed over to me and it is a pain to work around it. The entire solution is a giant hack. The data is not even dynamically generated. The data comes from a CMS or provided manually by a third party that I don't have the privilage to change at the source. So, this is the reason that I am asking the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a custom Json Converter.

```
public class JsonDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(string));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return reader.Value.ToString().DateTimeFormatter("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }


        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

        }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
        [JsonProperty("inception_date")] 
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDateTimeConverter))]
        public string InceptionDate { get; set; }
```

DateTimeFormatter is an extension method.

```
  public static string DateTimeFormatter(this string possibleDatetime, string format)
        {

            DateTime result;
            if( DateTime.TryParse(possibleDatetime, out result))
            {
               return result.ToString(format);
            }

            return possibleDatetime;
        }
```